# Make Title Selectable

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have the following code in which I want to make the title as selectable. As it is a header the .x-selectable class is getting added.

**The code is as follows**

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    store: userStore,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    title: 'Application Users',
    columns: [
        {
            text: 'Name',
            width: 100,
            sortable: false,
            hideable: false,
            dataIndex: 'name'
        },
        {
            text: 'Email Address',
            width: 150,
            dataIndex: 'email',
            hidden: true
        },
        {
            text: 'Phone Number',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'phone'
        }
    ]
});
```

Is there any work around for this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `selectable()`

> **selectable( ) : Ext.Element**
>   Enable text selection for this element
>   (normalized across browsers)

You need need to get your grid title header element & need to call this function.

Like this:

```
<yourGrid>.getHeader().el.selectable();
```

Can be done in `afterrender` listener of grid:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(grid){
        grid.down('header').getHeader().selectable();
    },
},
```

**For EXTJS 3.3.1** we need to remove the **selectStart** listener applied by default by extjs using `removeAllListeners()`:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(panel){
        panel.header.removeAllListeners();
    }
}
```

Comment: where will i add this code ? In css or my view page

Comment: need to add it in `afterrender` listener of grid in view page.See my updated answer

Comment: I'm trying with Panel. When i'm doing, it says Panel.down is not a function

Comment: You can do this with any dom element. Actually grid panel is inherited from panel. I modified example, so there is panel and down('header') is bad practice, use getHeader() instead: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/vf1

Comment: I'm using ExtJS 3.3.1. And it's giving me grid.getHeader() is not a function.

Comment: Ohh..You could have told it earlier.Anyways for ExtJs 3.3.1.We have some other solution as it dosen't support `selectable()`

Comment: then..can u share your code? Or if you are getting error?

Comment: @ankitchaudhary It is working now had to remove the x-unselectable class and add a new x-selectable as Internal CSS component and your codes follows it. Will accept your answer. thank you and yorlin http://stackoverflow.com/users/1154078/yorlin